# Navigation drawer reload issue in android

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer in my application. I want to change navigation drawer layout on a button tap. but each time i toggle the layout, it is simply added to the existing navigation drawer(duplicate entry is showing), but i want to replace the whole view to the new one.

How can i implement this ?

Please refer my code

```
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    if (checkIsLoggedIn()){
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer_logged_in);
    }
    else{
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer_logged_out);
        addHeaderLayout(navigationView);
      }
```

Here i have inflated activity_main_drawer_logged_in and activity_main_drawer_logged_out in the code as per the status of checkIsLoggedIn().

Issue:
If I logout from the application while navigation drawer is showing the layout for login

Then the contents of both activity_main_drawer_logged_out and activity_main_drawer_logged_in layouts is showing in the navigation drawer.

Comment: What do you mean added? Show the code

Comment: Its unclear what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to your code

```
if (checkIsLoggedIn()){
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer_logged_in);
}
else{
    navigationView.getMenu().clear();
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer_logged_out);
    addHeaderLayout(navigationView);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working for me. But duplicate header view is showing

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem while using the above answer. **Duplicate header view is showing**

I found a better solution for navigation view header duplicate while add header view dynamically. This is the code snippet.

```
if (navigationView != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < navigationView.getHeaderCount(); i++) {
   if (navigationView.getHeaderView(i) != null)
   navigationView.getHeaderView(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   addHeaderLayout(navigationView);
  }
```